# Position div relative to another element

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to position a div withing another element but make it stay in place when a page is scrolled vertically. The parent element is longer then the screen height. Can that be done with just CSS or do I need to use jQuery (that's what i normally use)? I'd use fixed position but am not sure how to associate it relative to the parent div...

```
<div id="veryHighDiv">
   <div id="positionMe"></div>
</div>
```

So, I need it to be position relative to the parent in term of horizontal position, but "fixed" when it comes to vertical scroll.

Comment: position div absolute to parent item and adjust it's 'top' on scroll event

Comment: So, it's a combo solution of CSS and jQuery?

Comment: `position:fixed` is supposed to be relative to the browser window, not to any parent element.

Comment: Having an element relative to the viewport vs. having an element relative to a parent element are two different relationships. Could you be more clear what you want the element to do?

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking how to accomplish this... I need it to be position relative to the parent in term of horizontal position, but "fixed" when it comes to vertical scroll.

Comment: You can't make a div relative to one element and fixed to another at the same time by CSS only.

Comment: I said you **can not** :) So you definitely will need some sort of JS

Comment: OK, I was making sure I explored CSS options before going down JS path... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple with jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/zA3mq/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#positionMe").css('position', 'fixed');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you ultimately want it to be fixed position, there's no need to start it off as relative since changing it to fixed dynamically will ruin any CSS work you do within relative (or usually absolute as well) positioning.

If it were me, I'd write a function to calculate where the fixed element should be, and then be sure to call that on all window events like load and resize so that it stays in place.  Here's a sample, but you'll likely need to change it based on the rest of your CSS:

```
<script>

$(window).load(function() {
    positionElem();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    positionElem();
});

function positionElem() {
    var padFromDiv = 30; // amount of padding you want from your div
    var newX = 0; // initialize newX at 0

    // get difference in window and veryHighDiv if window is larger
    if ($(window).width() > $('#veryHighDiv').width()) {
        newX = ($(window).width()-$('#veryHighDiv').width());
    }

    newX+=padFromDiv;

    $('#positionMe').css('left',newX);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I was leaning towards something like this. Actually I was about to follow advise of @Mohammad Ali Akbar and initially position the div relative to parent and then adjust the top value but I think your solution is making it simpler. In fact I can probably get a X coordinate off any other element in this parent div and parse into the new div, while keeping the bottom or top value fixed.

Comment: Exactomondo.  @Zoltan Roth gave something that is nice if you just need to switch to fixed, but from my point of view the element should already be fixed in your CSS, and that method does nothing for you to make it appear relative to the verHighDiv element.

Answer (score 1):

If you attach an absolute styled div to a relative div I believe that it will stay stuck to wherever the relative div is.

```
<div id="veryHighDiv">
       <div id="positionmMe"> </div>
    </div>

#veryHighDiv {
  position: relative;
}

#positionMe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}
```